# How to use djangorestframework-camel-case with drf-spectacular for camelcase schema

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I have set up `djangorestframework_camel_case`  and it works for rendered response data in  swagger-ui (drf-spectacular) - camel case response is generated. But the schema generated in the swagger-ui is still snake-case.  How can I make sure it also applies camel case to schema?

I see this [PR](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/pull/73/files) that apparently adds support for `djangorestframework_camel_case`, not sure exactly if it is expected to work out of the box, nothing in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in spectacular_settings:

```
    'CAMELIZE_NAMES': False, 
    
    'POSTPROCESSING_HOOKS': [
        'drf_spectacular.contrib.djangorestframework_camel_case.camelize_serializer_fields',
        'drf_spectacular.hooks.postprocess_schema_enums'
    ],
```

[Thanks to](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/issues/877)